# How to improve GWT performance?

Tags: performance, gwt

I am using GWT 2.4. There are times when I have to show huge amount of records for example: 50,000 records on my screen in a gridtable or flextable. But it takes very long to load that screen say around 30 mins or so; or, ultimately the screen hangs or at times IE displays an error saying that this might take too long and your application will stop working, so do you wish to continue.

Is there any solution to improve gwt performance?

Comment: What you're doing sounds strange, why not load them lazily? Surely the user can't see all 50000 records at once.

Comment: To load the data lazily, You can use paging with particular limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bring all data at once, you should bring it in pages, as the comments suggested here. 
However, paging not be trivial , as it might be that during paging your db is filled with more entries, and if you're using some sorting algorithm for the results, 
the new entries might ruin your sorting (for example, when trying to fetch page #2, some entries that should have been on the first page are inserted. 
You may decided that you create some sort of "cursor" for paging purposes and it will reflect the state of your database at the point you created it, so you will ignore entires that are entered during traversal between pages. 
Another option you may consider, as part of paging is providing only a small version for each record - i.e - only the most important details, and let the user double click if he wants to see the whole details for the record - this can also provide you some performance improvement within each page.